# If $K/F$ is a finite extension of fields what is $K \otimes_F F[X]$?

Tags: proof-verification, tensor-products

Suppose that $K/F$ is a finite extension of fields with $[K:F] = n$.  Then since $K$ is an $n$-dimensional $F$ vector space, we have $K \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n F$.  Then 
\begin{align*}
K \otimes_F F[X] &\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n F \otimes_F F[X]
\\
& \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n (F \otimes_F F[X])
\\
& \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n F[X].
\end{align*}
Is this right?  For some reason I feel like I'm missing something.  In particular, the way I used the assumption $[K:F] = n$ is bothering me.  Also, $F[X]$ is just sitting there and could easily have been any $F$ module.

Comment: Show that $K\underset{F}{\otimes} F\cong K$ as an $F$-algebra.  ($K$ can be any extension, not just a finite extension.)

Comment: $K\otimes_F F[X]\cong K[X]$ for **any** extension of fields.